# How to find the Page Load Sample Report in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In this [article](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/09/09/guide-to-google-analytics-site-speed-metrics/) about making sense of the Site speed related data in Google Analytics. The author mentions about a report that has both the *Page Load Sample* and Avg. Page Load time. I am unable to find this *Page Load Sample* report or add it as an additional dimension in my Site Speed related reports next to the Avg. Page Load Time. Any directions in this regards would be helpful. I google around and it seems there is a chance this may have been phased out of Google Analytics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the "Technical" tab in Site Speed Page Timings report

[image]